# Google SSO login error: "popup_closed_by_user"

Tags: google-signin

After setting up and running with my own client id I go through the login process and select the needed google account in the popup.

Once this has been selected the login fails with the error in the console being:

```
err = {error: "popup_closed_by_user"}
```

can anybody help me to solve this

Comment: similar thread and my [answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56720682/7336576)

Comment: this happened to me in incognito mode. Working fine in normal mode

Answer (score 43):

Try clearing your browser cache.

In Chrome: Settings → Advanced → Clear browsing data → Cached images and files

Comment: Allow third party cookies in your chrome.

Comment: Just a note, deleting cookies on the single page may not work, clearing browser cache will.

Comment: Will all users have to make this process so they can login in my site via Google?

Comment: @IsaacMuniz no, they shouldnt but occasionally maybe

Comment: Don't forget to also restart the browser after changing settings! I wasted an hour before realizing that restarting browser is required for settings to take effect...

Answer (score 18):

For those who are facing this issue in 2022 you should notice that
By default, newly created Client IDs are now blocked from using the older Platform Library, existing Client IDs are unaffected. New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can set plugin_name to enable use of the Google Platform Library.

try to use the following library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google

and read this page:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

Google requires new OAuth clients to use the latest library, otherwise old library does not properly initialize, hence leading to this error.

also, you could use a clientID that you created before to use the react-google-login

Comment: This worked for me. How to get profile details of the loggedin user?

Comment: If you need profile data as well. you can use "gapi-script" which worked for me.

Comment: @YellowDigitalLabs could you please help me by providing some references? I am stuck in this for a long time.

Comment: Can it be solved without react?

Answer (score 15):

Even I faced same issues when I want to login using angular4-social-login. It is because of cookies and pop-up settings in the browser. It will work in IE without errors. In Chrome settings go to content settings in that change cookies settings and allow pop-ups.
Then clear cache and reload. the app.

Comment: This is working as i change allow pop -ups option from chrome setting but this is the only solution because how end user knows what is the issue.

Comment: Indeed, There should be a note informing about Pop-up blockers.

Answer (score 14):

If you are testing against **localhost with port** then we should `add port number` in google developer console on **Authorized JavaScript origins section** like below

http://localhost:3000

Hope this resolve the issue.

Comment: BTW to add Authorized JS origins
go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
then choose your project from the drop down menu at top left, next GCP logo,
then edit the desired credential,

Answer (score 13):

### 2022 react update!

I was facing the same issue.. after a lot of workaround I got to know that I was missing gapi initialization!

**Here are the steps:**

First install gapi-script

```
npm i gapi-script
```

import the gapi from gapi-script

```
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
```

then initialize in App()

```
gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    clientId:
      "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    plugin_name: "chat",
  });
});
```

after these steps your app should be working fine ^_^

### JS update

I am not 100% sure about JS workaround but including this might work on your application

```
window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        window.gapi.client.init({
            clientId: '******.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            plugin_name: "chat"
        })
})
```

Comment: i've tried all ways below and only this works for me, i'm using window.gapi in this case.

Comment: Worked for me and I am using 1st 3 steps of the code

Answer (score 9):

I have a same issue, after add port number to url in google developer console and clear cache for current page, everything working perfect.

[image]

Comment: Empty cache and Hard Refresh fixed this immidiately

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

`popup_closed_by_user`  issue has occurred because of chrome blocks all the third-party cookies by default. You have to allow a third-party cookie from chrome setting.

But we can't ask our customers to allow a third-party cookie for this. The best solution for this maybe you can call google APIs (validate google account) at your backend and this issue will not occur at the backend.

Answer (score 3):

I open the Google OAuth-dialog using a simple login-button and some JavaScript. By default, my application sets the `cross-origin-opener-policy` to `same-origin`. This results in a `popup_closed_by_user` message on the JavaScript console of the browser.

By setting the `cross-origin-opener-policy` HTTP header at least to `same-origin-allow-popups` for the response delivering the window containing my login button, I could solve this issue.

Comment: Oh man, I was stuck at this from last 3 days, cause I had to set these header's to use ffmpeg, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to avoid popups altogether, by setting the `ux_redirect` option to `redirect`, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig):

> The UX mode to use for the sign-in flow. By default, it will open the consent flow in a popup. Valid values are `popup` and `redirect`.

That is, your `gapi.client` initialization should look something like this:

```js
gapi.client.init({
   apiKey: API_KEY,
   clientId: CLIENT_ID,
   discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
   scope: SCOPES,
   ux_mode: 'redirect'
}).then(function () {
    ....
});
```

Note that `ux_mode` is not a documented config option for `gapi.client.init`, only for `gapi.auth2.init`. This works because the former lazily initialises the latter, forwarding its own config.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
function AuthPage() {  
useEffect(() => {
 function start() {
 gapi.client.init({
 clientId:"''''''''''''''''''",
 scope: 'email',
   });
    }
   gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
    }, []);

  const onSuccess = response => {
  console.log('SUCCESS', response);
   };
  const onFailure = response => {
    console.log('FAILED', response);
    };
   const onLogoutSuccess = () => {
    console.log('SUCESS LOG OUT');
     };

    return (
    <div>
   <GoogleLogin
   clientId={"________________"}
  onSuccess={onSuccess}
  onFailure={onFailure}
    />
  <GoogleLogout
    clientId={"________________"}

    onLogoutSuccess={onLogoutSuccess}

      />
    </div>
    );

}

export default AuthPage;
```

##This is the latest solution for  this problem##

Comment: This worked without any issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**These steps will save you from this error:**

1. `yarn add gapi-script`
2. `import { gapi } from "gapi-script";`
   Add in the file in which you have add the GoogleLogin.
3. ```
   window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
       window.gapi.client.init({
           clientId: 'your client id will be display here',
           plugin_name: "chat"
       })})
   ```

That will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
```

})

this solved my issue although u need to process the data and make sure its the google auth ur getting

Answer (score 0):

this problem accures beacuse of the update in react i think.just use gapi and the problem will solve.use this [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-adding-google-login-react-app/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const clientId = "your token";

useEffect(() => {
 gapi.load("shareme_frontend:auth2", () => {
  gapi.auth2.init({clientId:clientId})
 })
}, []);

<GoogleLogin 
 clientId={clientId}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the issue follow the steps below (React):

1- install gapi-script.

```
npm i gapi-script --force
```

2- import gapi inside your login component.

```
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
```

3- write down this code inside you're response const.

```
gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN,
    plugin_name: "chat",
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by using the old `gapi.auth2.init()` authentication approach instead of the new `google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient()` [gsi approach](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js#set_up_the_sample) as well as using the old v2 docs instead of [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) and [the inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74934960/2750743) between the docs sample code with the actual format expected by [the library](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

Answer (score 0):

I am just using normal javascript. So to fix this I did the following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After loading the script ('//apis.google.com/js/platform.js'), in the DOM will also be inserted iframe, e.g.:

```
<body>
  ...
  <iframe aria-hidden="true" id="ssIFrame_google" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe#origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&amp;rpcToken=902946799.4541115&amp;clearCache=1" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -9999px; display: none;"></iframe>
</body>
```

At first, I did not understand why Google does this, so I just deleted this element:

```
const iframeElem = document.getElementById('ssIFrame_google');
if (iframeElem) {
  iframeElem.remove();
}
```

but when I reached the stage of processing the response about successful authentication, I faced the error described by you: popup_closed_by_user.
When I commented out my code to remove iframe - sign in was successful.

--
I can assume that your browser filters the content and removes this iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Change port number and run the app again. To change the port number you need to update port number under `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 }
```

Note: Here port number is changed to 3006.

Now, run application using `npm start`.

Answer (score -1):

Check that your `onsuccess` method doesn't throw any errors.

In my case, all failures in `onsuccess` method were falling into `onfailure` with `{ error: "popup_closed_by_user" }` argument, without any error messages in devtools console.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with Firebase auth, but in my case `localhost` was already present in my config. I needed to specifically add my local IP address (for testing on mobile) to the Authorized Domains list as well.

Answer (score -1):

IF you are in development mode and you are using your PC's `IP address` to access the site on mobile,Make sure you `add the IP address to the authorized domain in firebase`.

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

If you are using '@abacritt/angularx-social-login' for social media login using Angular, the below fix worked for me. This issue happens for all the newly created Client IDs. This can be overcome by adding 'plugin_name' in the provider for Angular.

In app.module.ts, create an object which holds the 'plugin_name'.

```
const googleLoginOptions = {
  scope: 'profile email',
  plugin_name:'sample_pwa_login'
};
```

And in  providers, pass the 'googleLoginOptions' object along with the google client ID.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
        {
          provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
          useValue: {
            autoLogin: false,
            providers: [
              {
                id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
                  'YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT_ID', 
                   googleLoginOptions
                )
              }
            ],
            onError: (err) => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
        }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Now, clear the browser cache and it should be working.
For the changes in app.component.ts you may refer to [@abacritt/angularx-social-login- documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login)

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by changing the `src` attribute of the script element from `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` into `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js`