# Error "permission type field is required" when attempting to create permission via Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I adapted code from the Google Drive API Quickstart for Node.js found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs%20%22here%22.) to try and create a new permission on an existing file in Google Drive.

No matter what I change in the code, I always get the same response saying `The permission type field is required` even though I've specified it via `resource` as mentioned in documentation for the npm `googleapis` [client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) and other examples I've found.

Is this just not working or am I missing something obvious?

#### Code to update permission

```js
function updateFilePermissions(auth) {

  var drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: auth
  });

  var resourceContents = {
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com'
  };

  drive.permissions.create({

    resource: resourceContents,
    fileId: aValidFileId,
    sendNotificationEmail: false,
    fields: 'id',

  }, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {

      // Handle error...
      console.error(err);

    } else {

      console.log('Permission ID: ', res.id);

    }

  });

}
```

#### Response from Google Drive API

```
code: 400,
errors: 
 [ { domain: 'global',
     reason: 'required',
     message: 'The permission type field is required.',
     locationType: 'other',
     location: 'permission.type' } ]
```

Comment: Can you try placing the individual values of your resourContents object inside drive.permissions.create? Put it manually there.

drive.permissions.create({

    resource: resourceContents,
    fileId: aValidFileId,
    sendNotificationEmail: false,
    fields: 'id',
    type: 'user',
    role: 'writer',
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com'

  }

Comment: Thanks. I get the same error when trying this unfortunately.

Comment: Making no other assumptions, if I was trying to solve this, the first thing I'd do is debug at the call to drive.permissions.create() and inspect resourceContents to be POSITIVE it is what you expect. To take that further, construct your entire object to be passed and do the same just before making that call. I bet something will jump out at you that clarifies it (if you haven't already). In case you don't have it handy, you may also want to copy/paste the following and see if you can get that working in context, then mutate it to your needs. That's how I'd do it anyway.

Answer (score 9):

To anyone that's still looking at the answer, it needs to be formatted like this:

```
  {
          fileId: fieldID, // String
          resource: {
            role: putRoleHere, //String
            type: putTypeHere //String
          }
```

Google's APIs are using Axios for the HTTP client so it will be auto-stringified for you when using their methods :)

Comment: Well that wasn't easy to figure out from their docs! Thanks

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but what makes this answer different from the OP's code except for stripping `emailAddress`, `sendNotificationEmail` and `fields` parameters? Does the answer imply that `putRoleHere` and `putTypeHere` are supposed be something other than strings? Some constants that we have to import from the library perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the sample code for [this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%2218TnwcUzeBGCHpr7UWW-tKjf2H2RKOKx2V2vaQiHR-TA%22%2C%22emailMessage%22%3A%22huj%20sosi%22%2C%22sendNotificationEmail%22%3Atrue%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22role%22%3A%22reader%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22emailAddress%22%3A%22safronevev%40gmail.com%22%7D%7D#try-it) produced by the docs is invalid. By analyzing outgoing requests in the devtools Network and a bit of guessing I found out that the `resource` fields must be placed in the root level alongside the `fileId`.

```js
response = await gapi.client.drive.permissions.create({
    fileId: "18TnwcUzeBGCHpr7UWW-tKjf2H2RKOKx2V2vaQiHR-TA",
    emailMessage: "huj sosi",
    sendNotificationEmail: false,
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com',
})
```

Considering that docs don't encourage using a specific version of [the library](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client), I suppose there was just a random breaking change in it at some point causing the inconsistency in the docs.