# How do I call create permissions on Google Drive API via Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Delphi to call Google Drive Permissions API to create a permission on a team drive. All goes well with the setting on the Google Try It section, but my Delphi code isn't working.

```
reqPermissions.Body.Add('{role: "organizer",type: "user",emailAddress: "it_admin@mycompany.com"}');
```

I've tried supplying the type field as a parameter in the `Request` component, but this also doesn't work. Driving me nuts at the mo, so any help much appreciated.

I always get the following response:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "The permission type field is required.",
        "locationType": "other",
        "location": "permission.type"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The permission type field is required."
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your request through PostMan or some other HTTP client?  Does it work or return the same error?  Seems like there's something wrong with your request body.

Comment: You says "It doesn't work". We cannot help you much without error message you get and the code you use to build and send your request.

Comment: Apologies, but just tried in Postman and got the same error. The closest thing I found on google was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751991/error-permission-type-field-is-required-when-attempting-to-create-permission-v

Comment: But I'm not sure how to format the body correctly as his advice doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Have you used correctly [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) ? Also, note that normally you would set the permissions like ```"role" : "organizer"``` and not like the way you implemented it ```role:"organizer"```. Could you try encapsulating the key in ```"``` and let me know if you still get the same error message?

Comment: Using oAuth 2.0 correctly using a Bearer token. I've tried various methods of formatting the body, although that does indeed appear to be the problem as I get Bad Request The request cannot be fullfilled due to bad syntax.

Comment: Using oAuth 2.0 correctly using a Bearer token. I've tried various methods of formatting the body, although that does indeed appear to be the problem as I get Bad Request The request cannot be fullfilled due to bad syntax.

Comment: Hi ! Have you set the request parameter ```supportAllDrives``` to true? For shared Drive it must be set to true. Check [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) for more information regarding this parameter. Also, when I run the request with that parameter set and with ```Try this API``` it did work, the body was formatted in the following way : ```{
  "role": "organizer",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "email@email"
}```