# popup_closed_by_user error when trying to test google oauth in my web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-oauth

So i am trying to implement google login into my web application using angularJS. The popup opens up to login into my google account or to select one the existing accounts but after login the popup closes with an error in the console (popup_closed_by_user)

The problem is consistant 100% of the times i tried. I have tried it on chrome and edge, same result. clearing cookies and cache doesnt help. google + API and oauth is enabled. The origin url is added correctly. 
The code is in angularJS.

```
.directive('googleSignInButton',function(){
  return {
      scope:{
          gClientId:'@',
          callback: '&onSignIn'
      },
      template: '<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="onSignInButtonClick()">Sign in with Google</button>',
      controller: ['$scope','$attrs',function($scope, $attrs){
          gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            //load in the auth2 api's, without it gapi.auth2 will be undefined
              gapi.auth2.init(
                      {
                          client_id: $attrs.gClientId
                      }
              );
              var GoogleAuth  = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();//get's a GoogleAuth instance with your client-id, needs to be called after gapi.auth2.init
              $scope.onSignInButtonClick=function(){//add a function to the controller so ng-click can bind to it
                  GoogleAuth.signIn().then(function(response){//request to sign in
                      $scope.callback({response:response});
                  });
              };
          });
      }]
  };
});
```

Comment: When writing a question, add 4 spaces before each line of your code sections. You can edit the post now. Makes it more readable.

Comment: edited .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

For newly created google clientIDs, we need to pass 'plugin_name' also , along with client ID. Otherwise we get the 'popup_closed_by_user' error no matter how many times you clear the cache.

The reason for this issue is given in here - [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)

In the above case we can pass 'plugin_name' with client ID , to resolve the issue

```
gapi.auth2.init(
                  {
                      client_id: $attrs.gClientId,
                      plugin_name: "hello" // you may use any custom name here
                  }
          );
```

Answer (score -1):

adding [gapi.auth2.SignInOptions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2signinoptions) e.g `{ prompt : 'consent' }`  to signIn function will force the popup to open.