# react-google-login is not working on my incognito browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, oauth, frontend

I tried to add the login with google function on my project.
My code is like followings:

```
<GoogleLogin
            clientId="my clientId"
            buttonText="Sign in with Google"
            onSuccess={handleSuccess}
            onFailure={handleFailure}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
            className="btn-google"
        />
```

It is working on general browsers, but not working on incognito browser.
On incognito, I got the following error just after entering all credentials of my google account.

```
{error: "popup_closed_by_user"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google login error: "popup\_closed\_by\_user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683320/google-login-error-popup-closed-by-user)

Comment: It is not the same error, I think. In my case, it is working well on the general browser, but not working on just the incognito browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. As far as I know, this is because incognito window disable cookies. My production users are facing it in recent versions of Chrome browsers too, where the cookies are (for some reason) disabled. What I found on my research is to replace the authentication a server side authentication to solve the problem. However, I have not yet tried and this can be a huge impact in the whole authentication flow.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have also fixed this issue by setting the authentication on the server side.