# Google Oauth popup cancellation callback

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

When using Google Identity Services (GSI) I can display a popup to ask users to connect with their Google account.
This is pretty well documented and it works well with this code:

```js
const client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'SCOPE',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  callback: async (response) => {
    console.log('Response Google', response);
  },
});
client.requestCode();
```

However, I wish to do something if the user close the popup. I can't find anything in the documentation and in examples online. I tried `intermediate_iframe_close_callback` and `native_callback`, but neither are called when closing the popup.

So, is it possible ? How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a nice solution to this where you add a focus event listener on the window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485415/4875396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the callback name is "error_callback". You can find details at: [Handle Errors](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/error)

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  callback: myCallback,
  error_callback: myErrorCallback  // You can do something when popup window closed
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is not working for the current version of GSI.

It did work for the old `gapi` version and if the popup were to be closed you would get a response with the error: `{error: "popup_closed_by_user"}`. As referenced in this answer: [Google SSO login error: "popup_closed_by_user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683320/google-sso-login-error-popup-closed-by-user)

Hopefully adding the #google-oauth tag will allow someone at Google to see this and hopefully update this script.